# Using a UserPermissionService by all Presenters in the Application to control the access to commands

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, mvp

I'm handling user permission in a MVP Winforms application as follows. Here I'll give a full detail of my code as it will be helpful when answering to this question.

My user model has a list called `permissions` which holds the permissions of the current user.
(eg: `CAN_EDIT_ACCOUNT`)

```
public class User
{
    //
    //
    List<stirng> Permissions = new List<string>();
}
```

In `Programe.cs` I instantiate required objects and services as follows. Please note that I'm using a single presenter for both login and main views. (Hope MVP doesn't stop me doing that)

```
Programe.cs

    static void Main()
    {
        frmLogin loginView = new frmLogin (); // Login form
        User userModel = new User();            
        DataService dataService = new DataService();
        UserPermissionService ups = new UserPermissionService();
        frmMain mainView = new frmMain(); // Application's main window

        LoginPresenter presenter = new LoginPresenter(loginView,mainView, userModel, dataService, ups);
        presenter.Show();            
    }
```

`UserPermissionService` is supposed to handle giving permission on request. At the creation of this service in the above code, its not aware of the user as the user is yet to login. So that Method Injection will be used.

There is a bool property for each module or feature that we need to control permission. If the respective `permission` is in the `permissions` list of the user, the property will be set to `True`.

```
public class UserPermissionService
{
    private User _user = null;

    public void InjectUser(User user) // User injected
    {
        _user = user;
    }

    public bool CanAccessBankAccountModule
    { 
        get { return _user.Permissions.Contains("BANKACCOUNT"); } 
    }
    //
    //
}
```

**LOGIN**

When the user presses `OK` button after supplying user credentials, it will validate it as follows. `LoginPresenter` will listen to the `OnValidatePassword` event and if its valid then the main window will be loaded and the user will be injected to the UserPermissionService. (please see `ValidatePassword()` method in `LoginPresenter` code)

```
public partial class frmLogin : Form
{
 private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OnValidatePassword(sender, e);
    }
}
```

**PERMISSION HANDLING**

Let's say the main form has buttons for every module and we need to enable a button if the user has permissions to access that particular module (eg. `btnBankAccountModule` should be enabled to access BANK ACCOUNT module if the user has permission). There is a `public bool property` for every `button` in the form and in the `Load` event, `OnControlPermission` will be fired and `LoginPresenter` will listen to this event and it will set the properties `True` or `False` based on the details provided by the `UserPermissionService`. (please see `ControlPermission()` method in the `LoginPresenter` code)

```
 public partial class frmMain : Form
 {
      public bool CanAccessBankAccountModule { get; set; }

      private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          OnControlPermission(sender, e);
          btnBankAccountModule.Enabled = CanAccessBankAccountModule; 
          //
          //
      }
 }


 class LoginPresenter
 {
      frmLogin _LoginView;
      frmMain _MainView;
      User _Model;
      DataService _DataService;
      UserPermissionService _UPS;

     public LoginPresenter( frmLogin loginView, frmMain mainView, User model, DataService dataService, UserPermissionService ups )
        {
            _LoginView = loginView;
            _MainView = mainView;
            _Model = model;
            _DataService = dataService;
            _UPS = ups;

            WireUpEvents();
        }

        void _MainView_OnControlPermission(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ControlPermission();
        }

        private void ControlPermission()
        {
            _MainView.CanAccessBankAccountModule = _UPS.CanAccessBankAccountModule;
            //
            //
        }

        void _View_OnValidatePassword(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ValidatePassword();
        }

        private void ValidatePassword()
        {
            var hash = Encryption.GetHash(_LoginView.UserID, _LoginView.Password);
            var user = _DataService.GetPermissions(_DataService.GetUser(_LoginView.UserID));
            if (user != null)
            {
                _Model = user;
                var hashInDB = _Model.PassWord;

                if (hash != hashInDB)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid password");
                    _LoginView.Valid = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    _UPS.InjectUser(_Model);
                    _MainView.PermissionsService = _UPS; //Optional
                    _MainView.ShowDialog();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid user name");
            }
        }

        public void Show()
        {
            _LoginView.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
```

Every thing seems fine up to the main window. My problem is, how should I make the `UserPermissinService` available to next level of UIs? (eg. To `frmBankAccount` view)

To provide the above service...

- Should my `LoginPresenter` communicate with `BankAccountPresenter`?

OR

- Could I have a public Property in main form as follows, which will then be passed to subsequent forms?

  ```
  public UserPermissionService PermissionsService { get; set; }
  ```

  This property will be set by the `LoginPresenter` with current instance of the `UserPermissionService`. (Please see this optional line in `LoginPresenter` code; `_MainView.PermissionsService = _UPS;` //  )

  Then, when the next presenter is instantiated in the main form... we can pass a reference to the current `UserPermssionService` instance, to the next presenter.

  ```
  var BankAccountPresenter = new BankAccountPresenter(modle, view, dataService, PermissionsService);
  BankAccountPresenter.Show();
  ```

  Is it Okay?

OR

- Is it better to instantiate an new instance of `UserPermissionService` in the Main form ? Then how should I inject the current user to the permission service?

Note : I am **not** familiar with IOC, so I'd appreciate if you could give an other explanation which would go inline with my current work?

Answer (score 2):

I am looking at this Method

> ```
>     private void ValidatePassword()
>     {
>         var hash = Encryption.GetHash(_LoginView.UserID, _LoginView.Password);
>         var user = _DataService.GetPermissions(_DataService.GetUser(_LoginView.UserID));
>         if (user != null)
>         {
>             _Model = user;
>             var hashInDB = _Model.PassWord;
>
>             if (hash != hashInDB)
>             {
>                 MessageBox.Show("Invalid password");
>                 _LoginView.Valid = false;
>             }
>             else
>             {
>                 _UPS.InjectUser(_Model);
>                 _MainView.PermissionsService = _UPS; //Optional
>                 _MainView.ShowDialog();
>             }
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             MessageBox.Show("Invalid user name");
>         }
>     }
> ```

and it doesn't appear that you really use `_Model` anywhere else, so I was thinking that you could just remove `_Model = user;` and use `user` wherever you were using `_Model`.

One other thing in this snippet, you should probably use a positive conditional for the if statements, so we just flip stuff around.

Like this

```
private void ValidatePassword()
{
    var hash = Encryption.GetHash(_LoginView.UserID, _LoginView.Password);
    var user = _DataService.GetPermissions(_DataService.GetUser(_LoginView.UserID));
    if (user != null)
    {
        var hashInDB = user.PassWord;

        if (hash == hashInDB)
        {
            _UPS.InjectUser(user);
            _MainView.PermissionsService = _UPS; //Optional
            _MainView.ShowDialog();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid password");
            _LoginView.Valid = false;

        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid user name");
    }
}
```

It just makes the code slightly cleaner.